# How to type the "~" key on Macbook Pro with Ubuntu？

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro

I install ubuntu 16.04.3 on my macbook-pro. But when I use the terminal, I find I cant type wave. When I type the wave key, it print "<" instead.

I think it's a text entry problem, maybe I choose the wrong input source. But I do use the English(US) text entry. Then I open keyboard layout chart, I know the reason. Every time I type the wave key, a weird key is shining which is left of the "z" and right of the "shift". I have never seen any keyboard has it before.

To solve the problem, I think I have to change a single key's reflection on the keyboard layout. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What do you expect to be typed? This `~`?

Comment: Yes, "~", now I type this "~" on my windows pc. @Pilot6

Comment: Have you got the keyboard layout set to 'Macintosh' ?

Comment: I have tried.But I still can't type "~". The situation is the same as I said.@CarlH

Comment: It works! Thank you!@CarlH Although "~" still reflect that weird key on the keyboard layout.